# Prevent an undefined into one line code

Tags: javascript

Using document command there are some times which is not exist. Instead of using controls like document contains or type of into one if statement is it possible to make the control into one line and if the command doesn't exist take an NA like this:

```
document.querySelector('div#name span.fn').textContent || "NA";
```

Comment: As for me, it is absolutely unclear what you mean :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

`(document.querySelector('div#name span.fn') || {}).textContent || "NA";`

If the `querySelector` call evaluates to null, it will return the object, which won't have a `textContent`, so it will return `NA`.

Comment: Of course, you should never write code like that, ever. It's completely unreadable and will be a pain to extend or maintain.

Comment: This answers the question, but I agree with @FrédéricHamidi in that this is ugly. There's no shame in breaking something like this into multiple lines of readable code.

Comment: It isn't the cleanest, but " It's completely unreadable and will be a pain to extend or maintain" is just silly and hyperbole.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function for something like this.

```js
function getTextContentOrDefault(selector, defaultValue) {
   var element = document.querySelector(selector);
   if (!element) return defaultValue;
   if (!element.textContent) return defaultValue;
   return element.textContent;
}

getTextContentOrDefault('div#name span.fn', 'NA');
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question specifically asks to do it in a single line.

Comment: Yes, it does. Put the function in a library and you've got reusable logic that can be called using one line. I think it's fair to assume that logic such as this will be used more than once. If you only answer the question exactly as asked, without proposing a potentially better alternative, then you are doing the original poster and broader community a disservice.

Comment: If that's the case then I can write anything in one line, by wrapping it in a function. It defeats the purpose of the question.

Comment: @Evan, I see where you're coming from, but Stack Overflow has an implicit "obligation of advice" (English is failing me tonight) that forces us to point out again and again that unreadable one-liners are very much not the way to write code in the industry. OTOH, one-liners are welcome on [codegolf.se].

Comment: To what extent? You don't know the situation the OP is in. By that logic I can should go to every vba question and say "well actually you should be using a n-tier architecture with a SQL database, you shouldn't use VBA in industry it's not correct practice". This doesn't answer the question as asked, simple as that. Don't know why everyone is getting so rustled over it.